# Attach SQLlite database to IPA file

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, ios5

I have searched inoformation to how attach local database to the IPA file to be submitted to Apple Store or Test Flight, but I wasn't successful. So I don't know exactly if:

1. Is it possible to attach the same db file I have created locally
   with all the data to IPA file? How can I do it?
2. If point 1 is not possible, Will I have to develop in the app
   delegate class the creation of the database scheme, and the
       insertion of the data auxiliary on the first run in the iPhone app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any file in the `Copy Bundle Resources` in the Xcode project build phases screen will be included in your apps bundle, and so also the ipa file, which as I understand it is simply a zipped application bundle possibly containing an adhoc provisioning profile.